# Creating a Stored Procedure for a Dynamic Pivot Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

After quite a while I was successful in writing a dynamic pivot query for my database.
Now I need to convert that to a Stored Procedure. I'm asking for the answer directly as I've quite less knowledge of Stored Procedures.
Below is the code and the parameters I need to pass are at the places ('01-01-2018'), ('12-01-2018'), (''04|02''), (''FTE 1'',''FTE2'',''FTE 3'')

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STUFF(
(
SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([MONTH]) 
FROM [MY_DB].[dbo].[ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT] 
WHERE [MONTH] BETWEEN ('01-01-2018') AND ('12-01-2018')
ORDER BY ',' + QUOTENAME([MONTH]) 
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') 

SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
FROM 
(
SELECT [MONTH],[MONTH END BILLABLE] 
FROM [MY_DB].[dbo].[ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT] 
WHERE [CC-LOC] = (''04|02'') AND [FTE/RATE CARD] IN (''FTE 1'',''FTE2'',''FTE 3'')
) x pivot (Sum ([MONTH END BILLABLE]) for [MONTH] in (' + @cols + '))p'
execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning your dynamic pivot query into a stored procedure does not require much modification :)

The key is defining variables to replace the hard-coded values you want to pass into the stored procedure. The following is a working stored procedure (named as usp_MonthEndBillableDynamicPivot):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_MonthEndBillableDynamicPivot(
    @MonthFrom datetime,
    @MonthTo datetime,
    @CC_LOC nvarchar(10),
    @FTE_RATE_CARD nvarchar(100)
)
AS
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STUFF(
(
SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([MONTH]) 
FROM [MY_DB].[dbo].[ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT] 
WHERE [MONTH] BETWEEN (@MonthFrom) AND (@MonthTo)
ORDER BY ',' + QUOTENAME([MONTH]) 
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') 

SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
FROM 
(
SELECT [MONTH],[MONTH END BILLABLE] 
FROM [MY_DB].[dbo].[ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT] 
WHERE [CC-LOC] = (''' + @CC_LOC + ''') AND [FTE/RATE CARD] IN (' + @FTE_RATE_CARD + ')
) x pivot (Sum ([MONTH END BILLABLE]) for [MONTH] in (' + @cols + '))p'
execute(@query)
```

I had to make some assumptions over the datatypes you have in your real ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT table. For testing purposes I created the following table in my own test database:

```
create table ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT(
    ID int identity(1,1) not null,
    MONTH datetime,
    [MONTH END BILLABLE] money,
    ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT int,
    [CC-LOC] nvarchar(10),
    [FTE/RATE CARD] nvarchar(100),
    constraint PK_ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT primary key(ID)
)
```

and populated it with the following test data (note i am using YYYY-MM-DD ISO date notation to reduce confusion between US and UK dates (my location))

```
insert into ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT([MONTH],[MONTH END BILLABLE],ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT,[CC-LOC],[FTE/RATE CARD])
values ('2018-01-01',10000.00,10,'04|02','FTE 1');

insert into ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT([MONTH],[MONTH END BILLABLE],ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT,[CC-LOC],[FTE/RATE CARD])
values ('2018-01-01',20000.00,20,'04|02','FTE 2');

insert into ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT([MONTH],[MONTH END BILLABLE],ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT,[CC-LOC],[FTE/RATE CARD])
values ('2018-01-01',30000.00,30,'04|02','FTE 3');

insert into ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT([MONTH],[MONTH END BILLABLE],ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT,[CC-LOC],[FTE/RATE CARD])
values ('2018-01-01',40000.00,40,'04|02','FTE 4');

insert into ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT([MONTH],[MONTH END BILLABLE],ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT,[CC-LOC],[FTE/RATE CARD])
values ('2018-02-01',10000.00,10,'04|02','FTE 1');

insert into ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT([MONTH],[MONTH END BILLABLE],ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT,[CC-LOC],[FTE/RATE CARD])
values ('2018-02-01',20000.00,20,'04|02','FTE 2');

insert into ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT([MONTH],[MONTH END BILLABLE],ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT,[CC-LOC],[FTE/RATE CARD])
values ('2018-02-01',30000.00,30,'04|02','FTE 3');

insert into ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT([MONTH],[MONTH END BILLABLE],ACTUAL_BILLABLE_HEADCOUNT,[CC-LOC],[FTE/RATE CARD])
values ('2018-02-01',40000.00,40,'04|02','FTE 4');
```

Please note i have included an additional 'FTE 4' value, which i used to check the dynamic nature of all this!

With all of the above, the stored procedure can be executed:

```
declare
    @MonthFrom datetime = '2018-01-01',
    @MonthTo datetime = '2018-12-01',
    @CC_LOC nvarchar(10) = '04|02',
    @FTE_RATE_CARD nvarchar(100) = '''FTE 1'',''FTE2'',''FTE 3'',''FTE 4'''
;

exec usp_MonthEndBillableDynamicPivot @MonthFrom, @MonthTo, @CC_LOC, @FTE_RATE_CARD;
```

with the following result:

[image: Example Results]

Hope that helps!